# Flutter desktop Mac: How to inherit the current working directory from Terminal?

Tags: flutter, macos

I have a desktop Flutter app that I created with `flutter create --platforms macos .` and deleted the sandbox entitlement.
When I run it with `flutter run -d macos`, its current working directory is inherited from the terminal:

[image]

However, if I build it and then run, the working directory is set to `/`

I build and run it like this:

1. `flutter build macos --release`
2. `open macos/Runner.xcworkspace`
3. In Xcode: Product \ Build.
4. Right click on Product, "Show in Finder".
5. Open Terminal there, it is `/Users/ai/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fpjufwclfcimfvgouqyfngfwkbfl/Build/Products/Debug`
6. `open current_directory_test.app`

[image]

How to inherit the working directory from the terminal when running a built app?

I am building an ad-hoc tool for my team and so do not care for the UX, so any other ways to pass a directory to the process will also do. I have heard of `open -a current_directory_test.app .`, but Mac shows an error message (with the correct directory name) without letting Flutter know it.

[image]

The code:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(Directory.current.path),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`flutter doctor`:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.5, on macOS 13.6 22G120 darwin-arm64
    (Rosetta), locale en-GE)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    ✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for
      more details.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)            
[✓] Network resources
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to inherit the working directory from the terminal when running a built app?

I don't know if there's a more Flutter-ish way to go about it, but on macOS (and iOS, etc.), you can get the environment variables from the shared ProcessInfo object. And since Unix systems store the working directory in an environment variable called `PWD`, you can get the working directory:

```
let workingDir = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["PWD"]
```

You'll get back an optional string. Note that if your app isn't launched from the command line, the environment may not contain a `PWD` variable, in which case you'll get nil.

It's unusual to launch a GUI app from the command line, and therefore unusual for a GUI app to care about the `PWD` environment variable. I'd encourage you to choose a different way to let the user choose a directory to operate on.

Comment: Thanks, PWD is correct, and I could get it the Dart way with `Platform.environment['PWD']`. It's only the higher-level getter `Directory.current` is wrong. I filed a bug in Flutter: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/135740

Comment: An app's current directory is normally different from the `PWD` variable. The current directory that Flutter is reporting probably comes from the FileManager's current directory property. Again, it's not common to launch GUI apps from the command line and have them operate on the shell's working directory; this doesn't seem like a bug to me.

Comment: Yes, we decided so after discussing there.